# Can't get DependencyResolver to work with ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I have this code in my bootstap of Ninject :

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    RegisterServices(kernel);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    return kernel;
}

private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    //TODO: Enregistrer les services ici.. pour ninject!
    kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<MySampleContext>();
    kernel.Bind<ISampleService>().To<SampleService>();
}
```

In my global i try this..

```
 protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            ContextProvider cp = new ContextProvider();
            DbContext context = (DbContext)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContext>();
            cp.SetCurrent(context);
        }
```

**EDIT**: Here the full bootstrapper... but its the basic one that come with ninjectt.

```
public static class NinjectMVC3 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(HttpApplicationInitializationModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        return kernel;
    }

    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //TODO: Enregistrer les services ici.. pour ninject!
        kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<MySampleContext>();
        kernel.Bind<ISampleService>().To<SampleService>();
    }        
}
```

but it return NULL ? why ?

Comment: You need to show the code for your "bootstrapper" Also, are you calling this on app_start?

Comment: Ive looked through debugging and everything are called without exception.. So the bootstrapper work.. and everying. What i try to do is lets the system to provider an IContext instance such MySampleContext..

Comment: @RubenBartelink: I don't have a problem with Ninject and you are right. I was honestly up late and just tired, shouldn't have made any comment.

Comment: @Paul: Grando. Ditto here re being up late and argumentative! Deleting my first comment as it makes no sense now. This will self destrcut if I get back here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ninject.MVC3 found on NuGet and read the documentation https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Comment: That what i used and this doesnt answer the question. The question is about providing an IContext instance such MySampleContext to a method..

Comment: You are not using the extension correctly. By setting DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel)); you are overriding the DependencyResolver of Ninject.MVC3 and from that point the extension is broken.

Comment: And define 
kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<MySampleContext>().InRequestScope(); and remove the Application_BeginRequest it's ensured by the binding that you get the same instance for the whole request so you won't need the ContextProvider anymore.

Comment: @Remo_Gloor Omg. You was so right. I don't need that ContextProvider.. By removing it ive been able to remove some code around. Now i don't even need to start a request and store the context. So if i understand.. the context is gonna be used for the whole request whhere its look for icontext ? Anyway on a side note you have to agree that the doc is not that good.

Comment: @Downvoter: what's the minus one doing if you're not prepared to explain why? Stick to facts and dont go fighting with vote buttons - it's very unbecoming.

Comment: @Rushino: The documentation is a wiki. Consider suggesting an edit (even as an edit into the wiki) in the place where the improvement you're talking about is possible. Specific complaints are far more useful than general ones.

Comment: Perhaps the comments pertinent to this question could go in the answer.